# NBitcoin - how to set RBF to true in order to give higher fee for transaction

Tags: doublespend, nbitcoin

I have a few transactions staying unconfirmed - been a few days now.

I suspect the minimum  mining fee was upped - 15 minutes prior I was still doing hundreds of transactions a day at that fee - but now it is not enough.

All documentation indicates this is an easy process - simply use the same TX as you used earlier.

I am now feeling that this is more involved.

I took the unconfirmed TX - and goot its prev_hash.

I loaded the TX of this prev_hash and resubmitted it to BlockCypher - and get the message :

```
Error sending transaction: Unable to lock an input of transactions xxx, likely already spent by yyy..
```

It correctly identifies that unconfirmed transaction in yyy placeholder.

Thus it does not want to spend it as its already spent.

Now there is a Readonly RBF property on NBitcoin.Transaction class.

RBF means "Replace by Fee" which is what I want to do - but I can't set it as it is read only.

How do I go about to indicate this is a RBF?

Answer (score 1):

NBitcoin just follow BIP125

```
public bool RBF
{
    get
    {
        return Inputs.Any(i => i.Sequence < 0xffffffff - 1);
    }
}
```

If you are using the `TransactionBuilder` for creating a transaction, you have two ways:

One is to use `TransactionBuilder.SetLockTime(blockHeight)` where block height is the `currentHeight-1` (actually, if you put 0 it will be fine as well)

The other way is to build your transaction without signing first with `TransactionBuilder.BuildTransaction(false)` change one of the input sequence, then use `TransactionBuilder.SignTransaction` to sign.

Answer (score 0):

According to [BIP 125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki#summary):

> Explicit signaling: A transaction is considered to have opted in to
>   allowing replacement of itself if any of its inputs have an nSequence
>   number less than (0xffffffff - 1).
>
> Inherited signaling: Transactions
>   that don't explicitly signal replaceability are replaceable under this
>   policy for as long as any one of their ancestors signals
>   replaceability and remains unconfirmed.

Does one of the inputs on your tx have a sequence number less than `0xffffffff - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

TransactionBuilder API has an easier way now to set RBF on, simply:

```
myTransactionBuilder.OptInRBF = true
```